# How to have a single google analytics account for multiple domains

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a Google analytic account which I'm using to track analytic of the domain a.com. Now I want to add b.com statistics to the same account. Given that they don't allow free Google analytic account creation anymore.

What I have done is according to this [article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite) and [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en). Both are the same.

Code are below here.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35089154-8']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.a.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

In the b.com domain I have below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35089154-8']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'www.b.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

But statics of b.com is not show in Google analytic account? How can I fix this?

Comment: Google Analytics is free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new property in the account (which will give you a new Account ID) and use that for domain b.

What is described in the article is cross domain tracking - that is needed only when you want to track two different domains so that they appear as one domain in your account (so you can for example track movements between the domains without losing campaign information).

Answer (score 2):

@Eike's answer is correct. Below are the steps how it should be done.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508?hl=en